# VSCode: History of previewed files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Single-click a file in the Explorer opens it in a preview mode and keeps reusing an existing Tab. Is there any way how to jump back to a previously previewed file?

**Update**

Keyboard shortcut I was looking for has changed in the latest VSCode release. To find it out open the command palette and type "go back".

Answer (score 4):

Yes - try the `Go Back` command (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>):

[image]